# Pass JQuery.FilterTable value from MVC Controller

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller

I am using Sunnywalker's FilterTable.  I am binding the filter table to a text box.  When first navigating to the page, I want to pass the textbox a value from the controller but can't get that part working.  The textbox populates but it does not start filtering the list.  Here is my code

```
@model IEnumerable<testSearch.Models.Material>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

Filter List: 
@Html.TextBox("Search", (string)ViewBag.LastActive)

<table id="MaterialList" class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Id)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description)
        </th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
        </td>
    </tr>
    }

</table>

@section css {
    <style>
        .filter-table .quick {
            margin-left: 0.5em;
            font-size: 0.8em;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        .fitler-table .quick:hover {
            text-decoration: underline;
        }

        td.alt {
            background-color: #ffc;
            background-color: rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.2);
        }
    </style>
}

@section scripts {
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/filtertable/jquery.filtertable.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#MaterialList').filterTable({
                inputSelector: '#Search'
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

And here is the controller code:

```
    public ActionResult Index(string lastActive, string nextActive)
    {
        ViewBag.LastActive = "Material1"; // lastActive;
        ViewBag.NextActive = nextActive;

        var materals = GetListOfMaterials();
        return View(materals);
    }
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

OK.  Figured out one way to do it.  I just added a click even after the page and javascript was loaded.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#MaterialList').filterTable({
            inputSelector: '#Search'
        });

        $('#Search').trigger("click");
    });
</script>
```